# Connection from Toad 11 to TFS 2010

Tags: toad

currently I try to connect to our TFS2010 server with Toad Team Coding.

I've tried to follow [this documentation](http://www.toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/649/Configuring-Toad%C2%AE-Team-Coding-to-use-Microsoft-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.aspx), but it's for Toad 10.6 and some of the windows look different. Still I was able to connect to our collection and see all our Team Projects we have.

The problems start, when I try to export something to TFS.

Team Coding Code Collections -> Create new revision...

There I select e.g. all Packages and click "OK", then I get the Export Options -> OK

Then I just get a bunch of errors:
"Unable to add revision from VCS repository. Error uploading file: C:\temp...."
The progess window in the background says: "Package xyz has been added to the VCS."

Now I have a bunch of PKS/PKB files in my folder and Visual Studio shows me, that I have new files with Pending Change "add". 
Team Coding Viewer shows me all the files with status "Available", checkin is grayed out, checkout gives the same error as above and the info window at the bottom shows:

> 15:29:46 Error: Cannot create file
>   "C:\Users\abc~1\AppData\Local\Temp\$111.11.1.11:1521\xxx.50510.PKB".
>   Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die
>   Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch

(Translation for the last part: Syntax of filename, foldername or diskname is wrong).

At this point it doesn't make sense to go on. Toad will show the files now as checked out, but in TFS they are still with the "add" change. Toad acts like the checkin/checkout was successful (window at the bottom) and shows the error for every file.

Any idea? Any new tutorial to set up Toad 11 with TFS 2010?